# Publish to separate folders in Artifact (GitHub Action)

Tags: github, github-actions

I have the following steps to publish and upload some files:

```
   - name: dotnet publish FA1
     run: dotnet publish Service/FA1/FA1.csproj --configuration Release --output fa1_publish_output
    
    - name: publish FA1 files
      uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
      with:
        name: ${{github.run_number}}
        path: |
          fa1_publish_output

    - name: dotnet publish FA2
      run: dotnet publish Service/FA2/FA2.csproj --configuration Release --output fa2_publish_output
    
    - name: publish FA2 files
      uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
      with:
        name: ${{github.run_number}}
        path: |
          fa2_publish_output
```

fa1_publish_output contains a file host.json and a folder fa1

fa2_publish_output contains a file host.json and a folder fa2

The Build succeeded however after downloading the artifact, I see the following structure:

[image]

Is there a way to update the above code such that artifact will contain the following structure?

```
fa1_app -> host.json
           fa1

fa2_app -> host.json
           fa2
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
   - name: dotnet publish FA1
     run: dotnet publish Service/FA1/FA1.csproj --configuration Release --output fa1_app
       
    - name: dotnet publish FA2
      run: dotnet publish Service/FA2/FA2.csproj --configuration Release --output fa2_app
    
    - name: publish files to artifact
      uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
      with:
        name: ${{github.run_number}}
        path: |
          fa1_app
          fa2_app
```